# Javascript variable overriden issue in Expo createCategoryAsync

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I know everyone may had this issue before and I think this one maybe the same but what I expected is the 'uniq_identifier' should be series numbers, like 0, 1, 2, 3....      but I always get 1 for ever.

```
enter code here
array.forEach(element => {
        let categoryId = 'categoryId'
        let body = 'Press and hold for more options, God bless USA!';
        console.log(`completeID-${element}`);
        var uniq_identifier = `completeID-${element}`;


        Notifications.createCategoryAsync(uniq_identifier, [
            {
              actionId: uniq_identifier,
              buttonTitle: `USA ${element}`,
              isDestructive: false,
              isAuthenticationRequired: false,
            },
            {
              actionId: 'God and me',
              buttonTitle: 'Delay',
              isDestructive: false,
              isAuthenticationRequired: false,
            },
        ]).then(() => {
            console.log('var in async: ', element);
        });
});
```

Comment: sorry I mean the 'element' in variable 'uniq_identifier', which is `completeID-${element}` always 1

Comment: Can you log the array object and do you mean it always 1 when you use console.log line like in question code?